# Serializers - one to many relation with user limit input

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with drf. I have device serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from smarthome.models import Device


class DeviceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=80)
    address = serializers.CharField(max_length=17)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Device.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Also, i have result serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from smarthome.models import Result
from smarthome.models import Device


class ResultSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    temperature = serializers.CharField(max_length=80)
    moisture = serializers.CharField(max_length=80)
    light = serializers.CharField(max_length=80)
    conductivity = serializers.CharField(max_length=80)
    battery = serializers.CharField(max_length=80)
    date = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    device = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Device.objects.all())

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        return Result.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

I dont know how to add device results to device serializer. Also i want to have possibility to use limit send from user to limit number of results in response.

There is my models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=17)


class Result(models.Model):
    temperature = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    moisture = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    light = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    conductivity = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    battery = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    device = models.ForeignKey('Device', related_name='statuses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now, in response i got:

> {
>    "id": 1,
>    "name": "name",
>    "address": "c4:7c:8d:6a:fb:27"
>   }

i want something like this:

> {
>    "id": 1,
>    "name": "name",
>    "address": "c4:7c:8d:6a:fb:27",
>    "results": {
>      {
>        "temperature": "21.5",
>        "moisture": "61",
>        ...
>      },
>      {
>        ...
>      }
>    }
>   }

Answer (score 0):

As your use case is very trivial, so instead of using `Serializer` class to declare your serializers, you should use [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer), which saves your code and manage lots of things for you.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from smarthome.models import Result
from smarthome.models import Device

class ResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = ('id', 'temperature', 'moisture', 'light', 'conductivity', 'battery', 'date')

class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    results = ResultSerializer(many=True, source='result_set')
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'address', 'results')
```

Now, on using `DeviceSerializer` for deserializing an instance of `Device` model, you will get expected output.

> { "id": 1, "name": "name", "address": "c4:7c:8d:6a:fb:27", "results": { { "temperature": "21.5", "moisture": "61", ... }, { ... } } }

Comment: Thanks you very much, i will try that. But i don't see possibility to limit rows from user input. It`s possible?

Comment: Unfortunately that not working. I got error `'Device' object has no attribute 'results'.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested serializer in this respect.
please see the official doc for [Nested relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Comment: I copy paste code from first answer, but that doesny work. All time i got error `'Device' object has no attribute 'results'`

Comment: did you try nested serializer. if you, then please show your serializers.py file.